# Python numpy reshape

Tags: python, numpy

I have a variable of z storing features of length and height of image files where z is

```
z = [length, height]
```

and i want to change these dimension to just:

```
z = [area] where area = length * height
```

I tried using the numpy reshape function as follow:

```
area = z.shape[0] * z.shape[1] #length * height
z = z.reshape(-1) #was trying to reduce to just z = [area]
```

but it seemed like I'm not using the reshape function correctly. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example of how to use reshape:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,10))
b = np.reshape(a, (100,))
print(b)
```

For your case it will be:

```
print(a.shape)  # prints (length,height)
b = np.reshape(a, (length * height,))
print(b.shape)  # prints (length * height,)
```

To perform a reshape in place you can also use:

```
a.shape = ((100,))
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! May i know what is the difference of using np.reshape() compared to a.reshape()?

Comment: Sure no problem. They do the same thing, but I like the np.reshape form over the array.reshape, since the array form may create the impression that the reshape is in place, with the np.reshape form its clear you need to assign. Please remember to accept and like the answer. ;-)